# Problems with aggregating attribute values and copy the entire XML structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML document:

```
<PrintOut>
<Header DateCreated="20010101" Status="1" />
<CalcInfo NetPrice="30222" DiscountPercent="0.05"  />
<OrderRows>
    <OrderRow RowID="11297" NbrOf="1">
        <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.01" ListPrice="1555"/>
        <OrderSettings>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
        </OrderSettings>
        <Components>
            <ComponentData>
                <Component ComponentID="AAAAA" SortOrder="33"></Component>
                <Properties>
                    <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="internal" PropertyValue="60.00"></Property>
                </Properties>                   
            </ComponentData>
            <ComponentData>
                 <Component ComponentID="aaaa" SortOrder="44"></Component>
                <Properties>
                    <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="100.00"></Property>
                </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
            <ComponentData>
                 <Component ComponentID="BBBB" SortOrder="22"></Component>
                <Properties>
                    <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="101.00"></Property>
                </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
        </Components>
    </OrderRow>
    <OrderRow RowID="11298"  NbrOf="1">
        <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.02" ListPrice="1666"/>
        <OrderSettings>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
        </OrderSettings>
        <Components>
            <ComponentData>
                <Component ComponentID="CCCCC" SortOrder="11"></Component>
                <Properties>
                    <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="pricecost" PropertyValue="5.00"></Property>
                </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
        </Components>
    </OrderRow>
    <OrderRow RowID="11299" NbrOf="1">
        <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.03" ListPrice="1777"/>
        <OrderSettings>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
        </OrderSettings>
        <Components>
            <ComponentData>
                 <Component ComponentID="DDDDD" SortOrder="00"></Component>
                <Properties>
                    <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="105.00"></Property>
                    <Property FamilyID="Saftey-Restriction" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="20000"></Property>
                </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
        </Components>
    </OrderRow>
    <OrderRow RowID="11300" NbrOf="1">
        <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.04" ListPrice="1888"/>
        <OrderSettings>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
        </OrderSettings>
        <Components>
            <ComponentData>
                 <Component ComponentID="EEEEE" SortOrder="-1"></Component>
                <Properties>
                    <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="75.00"></Property>
                    <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="internalprice" PropertyValue="270.00"></Property>
                </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
        </Components>
    </OrderRow>
    <OrderRow RowID="11301" NbrOf="1">
        <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.05" ListPrice="0"/>
        <OrderSettings>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
        </OrderSettings>
            <Components>
                <ComponentData>
                <Component ComponentID="FFFFF" SortOrder="-2"></Component>
                <Properties>
                    <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="internalprice" PropertyValue="70.00"></Property>
                </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
        </Components>
    </OrderRow>
</OrderRows>
</PrintOut>
```

For each OrderRow, I want to group and summarize for unique PropertyID's Property Value (found in element Property). The total for each PropertyID's PropertyValue should be created as new attribute in element OrderRow including  suffix "_Sum".
The solution should be able to handle that PropertyID is unknown in advance.
What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
    <PrintOut>
    <Header DateCreated="20010101" Status="1" />
    <CalcInfo NetPrice="30222" DiscountPercent="0.05"  />
    <OrderRows>
        <OrderRow RowID="11297" NbrOf="1" internal_Sum="60.00" costprice1_Sum="201.00">
            <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.01" ListPrice="1555"/>
            <OrderSettings>
                <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
                <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
            </OrderSettings>
            <Components>
                <ComponentData>
                    <Component ComponentID="AAAAA" SortOrder="33"></Component>
                    <Properties>
                        <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="internal" PropertyValue="60.00"></Property>
                    </Properties>                   
                </ComponentData>
                <ComponentData>
                     <Component ComponentID="aaaa" SortOrder="44"></Component>
                    <Properties>
                        <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="100.00"></Property>
                    </Properties>
                </ComponentData>
                <ComponentData>
                     <Component ComponentID="BBBB" SortOrder="22"></Component>
                    <Properties>
                        <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="101.00"></Property>
                    </Properties>
                </ComponentData>
            </Components>
        </OrderRow>
        <OrderRow RowID="11298"  NbrOf="1" pricecost_Sum="5.00">
            <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.02" ListPrice="1666"/>
            <OrderSettings>
                <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
                <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
            </OrderSettings>
            <Components>
                <ComponentData>
                    <Component ComponentID="CCCCC" SortOrder="11"></Component>
                    <Properties>
                        <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="pricecost" PropertyValue="5.00"></Property>
                    </Properties>
                </ComponentData>
            </Components>
        </OrderRow>
        <OrderRow RowID="11299" NbrOf="1" costprice1_Sum="20105.00">
            <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.03" ListPrice="1777"/>
            <OrderSettings>
                <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
                <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
            </OrderSettings>
            <Components>
                <ComponentData>
                     <Component ComponentID="DDDDD" SortOrder="00"></Component>
                    <Properties>
                        <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="105.00"></Property>
                        <Property FamilyID="Saftey-Restriction" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="20000.00"></Property>
                    </Properties>
                </ComponentData>
            </Components>
        </OrderRow>
        <OrderRow RowID="11300" NbrOf="1" costprice1_Sum="75.00" internalprice_Sum="270.00" >
            <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.04" ListPrice="1888"/>
            <OrderSettings>
                <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
                <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
            </OrderSettings>
            <Components>
                <ComponentData>
                     <Component ComponentID="EEEEE" SortOrder="-1"></Component>
                    <Properties>
                        <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="75.00"></Property>
                        <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="internalprice" PropertyValue="270.00"></Property>
                    </Properties>
                </ComponentData>
            </Components>
        </OrderRow>
        <OrderRow RowID="11301" NbrOf="1">
            <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.05" ListPrice="0"/>
            <OrderSettings>
                <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
                <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
            </OrderSettings>
                <Components>
                    <ComponentData>
                    <Component ComponentID="FFFFF" SortOrder="-2"></Component>
                    <Properties>
                        <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="internalprice" PropertyValue="70.00"></Property>
                    </Properties>
                </ComponentData>
            </Components>
        </OrderRow>
    </OrderRows>
</PrintOut>
```

The PropertyIDs I want to summarize, in this example, is internal, costprice1, pricecost and internalprice.
I almost got a solution with my xslt but not quite, as summary also ends up as attribute on element Properties and may not be with the whole structure of XML document. My XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="currency-key"
             match="/PrintOut/OrderRows/OrderRow/Components/ComponentData/Properties/Property"
             use="@PropertyID" />
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderRow">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Components/ComponentData/Properties/Property[generate-id() = generate-id(key('currency-key', @PropertyID)[1])]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Property">
        <xsl:attribute name="{concat(@PropertyID, '_Sum')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('currency-key', @PropertyID)/@PropertyValue)" />
       </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The solution should be XSLT version 1.0 (However, I am also curious how the solution might look like in version 2.0)
Some thougts about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="property" match="Property" use="concat(@PropertyID, ancestor::OrderRow/@RowID)" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OrderRow">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Components/ComponentData/Properties/Property[generate-id()=generate-id(key('property', concat(@PropertyID, ancestor::OrderRow/@RowID))[1])]">
            <xsl:attribute name="{@PropertyID}_Sum">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('property', concat(@PropertyID, ancestor::OrderRow/@RowID))/@PropertyValue)" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result, when applied to your input, will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PrintOut>
   <Header DateCreated="20010101" Status="1"/>
   <CalcInfo NetPrice="30222" DiscountPercent="0.05"/>
   <OrderRows>
      <OrderRow RowID="11297" NbrOf="1" internal_Sum="60" costprice1_Sum="201">
         <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.01" ListPrice="1555"/>
         <OrderSettings>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
         </OrderSettings>
         <Components>
            <ComponentData>
               <Component ComponentID="AAAAA" SortOrder="33"/>
               <Properties>
                  <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="internal" PropertyValue="60.00"/>
               </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
            <ComponentData>
               <Component ComponentID="aaaa" SortOrder="44"/>
               <Properties>
                  <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="100.00"/>
               </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
            <ComponentData>
               <Component ComponentID="BBBB" SortOrder="22"/>
               <Properties>
                  <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="101.00"/>
               </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
         </Components>
      </OrderRow>
      <OrderRow RowID="11298" NbrOf="1" pricecost_Sum="5">
         <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.02" ListPrice="1666"/>
         <OrderSettings>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
         </OrderSettings>
         <Components>
            <ComponentData>
               <Component ComponentID="CCCCC" SortOrder="11"/>
               <Properties>
                  <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="pricecost" PropertyValue="5.00"/>
               </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
         </Components>
      </OrderRow>
      <OrderRow RowID="11299" NbrOf="1" costprice1_Sum="20105">
         <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.03" ListPrice="1777"/>
         <OrderSettings>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
         </OrderSettings>
         <Components>
            <ComponentData>
               <Component ComponentID="DDDDD" SortOrder="00"/>
               <Properties>
                  <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="105.00"/>
                  <Property FamilyID="Saftey-Restriction" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="20000"/>
               </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
         </Components>
      </OrderRow>
      <OrderRow RowID="11300" NbrOf="1" costprice1_Sum="75" internalprice_Sum="270">
         <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.04" ListPrice="1888"/>
         <OrderSettings>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
         </OrderSettings>
         <Components>
            <ComponentData>
               <Component ComponentID="EEEEE" SortOrder="-1"/>
               <Properties>
                  <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="costprice1" PropertyValue="75.00"/>
                  <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="internalprice" PropertyValue="270.00"/>
               </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
         </Components>
      </OrderRow>
      <OrderRow RowID="11301" NbrOf="1" internalprice_Sum="70">
         <RowCalcInfo GrossProfit="33.05" ListPrice="0"/>
         <OrderSettings>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="1"/>
            <OrderSetting ParameterValue="2"/>
         </OrderSettings>
         <Components>
            <ComponentData>
               <Component ComponentID="FFFFF" SortOrder="-2"/>
               <Properties>
                  <Property FamilyID="Saftey" PropertyID="internalprice" PropertyValue="70.00"/>
               </Properties>
            </ComponentData>
         </Components>
      </OrderRow>
   </OrderRows>
</PrintOut>
```

In XSLT 2.0, you would use `xsl:for-each-group` to do the grouping, instead of the Muenchian method.